# Correct handling of Input Fields of type number in React with state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am running into an issue where if I enter a number in the form field, and then erase it, rather than showing an empty input field it is showing the number 0. This is because of how I currently have a set state element setup to parse the input value as a number. So when the user clears the input field with backspace it is converting an empty string to a 0.
This is leading to buggy behaviour because the user won't be able to clear the field completely to type a new number and any further entry would be prefixed with the 0.

How can I fix this so it should behave correctly? Thanks

```js
const AddWidget = () => {
  const [form, setForm] = useState({ name: '', mfg: '', price: '', inStock: '' })

  function handleInputChange (e) {
    const { name, value } = e.target
    const newForm = {
      ...form,
      [name]: (name === 'inStock' || name === 'price') ? Number(value) : value
    }
    setForm(newForm)
  }

  function handleFormSubmit (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    addWidget(form)
      .then((newWidget) => {
        console.log('newwidget', newWidget)
        setForm({ name: '', mfg: '', price: '', inStock: '' })
        return null
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error(err)
      })
  }

  return (
    <div className="ui container">
      <h2>Add New Widget</h2>
      <form className="ui form" onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
        <div className="field">
          <label htmlFor="name">Name:</label>
          <input type="text" name="name" value={form.name} onChange={handleInputChange} />
        </div>
        <div className="field">
          <label htmlFor="mfg">Manufacturer:</label>
          <input type="text" name="mfg" value={form.mfg} onChange={handleInputChange} />
        </div>
        <div className="field">
          <label htmlFor="price">Price</label>
          <input type="number" name="price" value={form.price} onChange={handleInputChange} />
        </div>
        <div className="field">
          <label htmlFor="inStock">Stock</label>
          <input type="number" name="inStock" value={form.inStock} onChange={handleInputChange} />
        </div>
        <button className="ui button">Add Widget</button>
      </form>

    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added just one more condition in your code to check if there is a value and if there isn't or the value equals false I return an empty string else your logic is applied. When I write in the field and then delete it, it stays blank which is the result you are seeking I hope.

```
  function handleInputChange(e) {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const newForm = {
      ...form,
      [name]: (name === 'inStock' || name === 'price') && !value ? '' 
      : (name === 'inStock' || name === 'price') && value ? Number(value) : value
    };
    setForm(newForm);
  }
```

P.S. You can apply the same logic using if statements if you feel more comfortable with them.